# How to auto-size comment box to fit its content?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to turn the text contents of a single cell into a comment on that cell and then have the comment auto size to fit the true size of the contents. I found two separate macros that work but I am having trouble combining them into one macro.

The below code works by converting the selected cell into a comment.
https://sumtips.com/tips-n-tricks/convert-excel-cell-contents-comments-vba/

```
Sub ConvertToComment()
Dim C As Range
For Each C In Selection
    C.ClearComments
    If Len(C.Value) > 0 Then
        C.AddComment
        C.COMMENT.Text C.Value & ""
    End If
    'Optional: Delete cell content after converting
    C = "See Comment"
    Next C
End Sub
```

The below code works in auto sizing all the comments on the sheet.
https://quadexcel.com/how-to-auto-size-comment-box-to-fit-its-content-in-excel/

```
Sub FitComments()
Dim xComment As Comment
For Each xComment In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments
xComment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Next
End Sub
```

How can I incorporate the below line into the ConvertToComment() macro at the top?

```
xComment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
```

The below code is my sad attempt to add a line I think is important to make it work the way I want it to. Create the comment and Autosize the created comment to fit the content. I am still very new to VBA.

```
Sub ConvertToComment()
Dim C As Range
Dim xComment As COMMENT
For Each C In Selection
    C.ClearComments
    If Len(C.Value) > 0 Then
        C.AddComment
        C.COMMENT.Text C.Value & ""
  -->   COMMENT.Text C.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End If
    'Optional: Delete cell content after converting
    C = "See Comment"
    Next C
End Sub
```

Error Message "Object doesn't support this project or method"

Comment: There are two statements on the same line. Try just `C.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have just tried this line in the place of my previous incorrect line. It gave error 438. "Object doesn't support this property or method". So I added ```C.COMMENT.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True``` and it worked. Thank you so much.